# ¿Por que mi apk de android estudio no instala?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

> ¿Por que mi apk de android studio no se completa la instalación?

Cuando lo emulo en el celular funciona de maravilla,pero cuando el apk lo quiero instalar no se completa la instalación, he probado varias veces pero sucede lo mismo,es una app que esta usando la api de google maps y pide permiso de ubicación, sospecho que es por eso, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como generas tu apk? si lo firmas?

Comment: No,solo el debug apk por defecto,podria ser eso talves

Comment: una vez una app de debug (donde solo le das run en la parte de arriba, flecha verde) extraje ese apk con una aplicacion de mi telefono para pasarlo a otro y no funciona, mi recomendacion es que crees un apk firmado, puedes generarla tanto en debug o release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error :

> "The package appears to be corrupt while installing apk file"

o

> "No se instalo la aplicación parece que el paquete está dañado".

Es causado principalmente por 3 causas,

- El .apk en realidad esta corrupto, te sugiero lo crees nuevamente y tomes el que se genera, puedes acceder a este archivo en "locate":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Estas tratando de instalar la aplicación pero existe una instalada que fue firmada con otro Kestore diferente, en este caso busca la aplicación y eliminala. Te sugiero ir a configuración > aplicaciones, busca y des instala la aplicación.
- En el dispositivo se encuentra instalada la aplicación pero con otro usuario diferente, te sugiero ir a configuración > aplicaciones , seleccionar la aplicación y dar clic en "Desinstalar para todos los usuarios" ( "Uninstall for all users").

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

me paso varias veces y el problema es el cable,por mas que te lo detecte a veces no pasa bien la aplicacion.
con un telefono me pasaba bien la aplicacion y usando el mismo cable con otro telefono,el cual supongo no tenia buen contacto con la ficha ( aunque si lo detectaba) no pasaba la aplicacion y tenia que recurrir a pasarlo de telefono a telefono via bluetooth o usar otro cable que hiciera mejor contacto en el telefono

Comment: Este problema no creo que tenga que ver con el cable, en realidad el .apk se encuentra en el dispositivo pero el problema surge al desempaquetar y tratar de instalar.

Comment: si,eso mismo me pasaba y con otro cable lo solucionaba,usa un cable de  calidad o  el original del telefono o alguno que haga buen contacto

Comment: no es cable en mi caso, genere varias veces la apk, y lo pase incluso mi app instalada de mi celular lo pase a otro celular y nada,no se puede instalar.

Comment: @Jhon primeramente asegura que no exista una aplicación instalada que pudiera ser creada con otro Keystore, eliminala y prueba.

Comment: Pero no entiendo,por que al emular se instala y funciona pero el apk no se instala,he generado varios y los pase por watsapp a mis amigos, y a todos le sale lo mismo